# Is there a way to consider multiple pages to extract using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pycharm, pypdf

I am trying to extract, rotate and rename the PDF's from columns (Page Num, Rotation Angle, New PDF Name) respectively. The code is working fine if the page numbers in excel are given as a single page (For ex: It works correctly if the page is either 8,18,88). But the code isn't working if there are multiple pages given (For ex: 8,18 as a single file// 9,10 as a single file etc.).

Is there a way to resolve this? Below is the code, I have been using:

```
import PyPDF2
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\rc06587\\OneDrive - Ryan LLC\\Desktop\\PDF Tool\\Sample.xlsx")

for index, row in df.iterrows():
pdf_path = row['File Path']
page_num = row['Page Num']
rotation_angle = row['Rotation Angle']
save_as = row['New PDF Name']

if rotation_angle == 'R':
    rotation_angle = 90
elif rotation_angle == 'U':
    rotation_angle = 180
elif rotation_angle == 'L':
    rotation_angle = -90
elif rotation_angle == 'D':
    rotation_angle = -180

with open(pdf_path, 'rb') as file:
    pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(file)
    total_pages = pdf.getNumPages()
    if page_num > total_pages:
        cell = sheet.cell(row=index+1, column=6)
        cell.comment = "Page Range Exceeded"
    page = pdf.getPage(page_num -1)
    page.rotateClockwise(rotation_angle)

    with open(save_as, 'wb') as new_file:
        pdf_writer = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()
        pdf_writer.addPage(page)
        pdf_writer.write(new_file)`
```

Comment: Easy with the **GIGANTIC** text.

Comment: @tadman -- I am a newbie here. Appreciate if you could elaborate or provide the code accordingly.

Comment: Some error occur?

Comment: @amkawai - No error. The code is working fine. But while executing the code when multiple pages given, it isn't executing the task

Comment: Tip: Instead of a bunch of `if` statements, consider using a look-up table. `ANGLE[rotation_angle]` where you have `ANGLE = { 'R': 90, ... }`.

Comment: I tried to reproduce this code on my computer, but thils line "if page_num > total_pages:" provoke a comparison error, because if page_num have a list like 1,2,3, this comparison doesn't make any sense... I suggest you treat separately the cases where more than one page is inputted...